# Joomla 3.1 install with Postgresql 9.3

Tags: postgresql, joomla

I just can't get this to work, I always get : Error connecting to PGSQL database.

I have PGSQL database installed and running, and I installed php server that is installed through PostgreSQL. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you entered the correct database details in the **configuration.php**? Trey reading this: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=707&t=759835

Comment: I am very sure I entered all information correctly. I didn't even get to the configuration, because this error is shown during the installation phase. I searched a lot online, none suggestion is helping and I did all the things stated in the link you provided.

Comment: Is this local on on  a live server?

Comment: Just localhost, I tried with localhost, 127.0.0.1 with correct port. and I am 100% sure postgresql server is up and running, and username and password is correct.

Comment: Could be a problem with client authentication. Is your DB hostname 'localhost'? Change the authentication method to 'trust' for local users in pg_hba.conf, restart pgsql service and check if the connection succeeds ...

Answer (score 0):

I came across this answer searching for help on the same issue and the farthest I got was with the help of this answer [Error connecting to PGSQL database in Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323906/error-connecting-to-pgsql-database-in-joomla) . Thereafter, I opened the Joomla core and determined that they have not accommodated a  host:port split in their postgresql driver.

Therefore, hacking INSTALL_PATH/libraries/joomla/database/driver/postgresql.php line 126, and accommodating the port information by changing the if clause to that pasted below, help me connect.

```
if (!empty($this->options['host']))
        {
            if(strpos($this->options['host'] ,":" )!== false){
                $host_p = explode(':' , $this->options['host']);
                if(count($host_p) == 2){
                    $host = $host_p[0];
                    $port = $host_p[1];
                    $dsn .= "host={$host} port={$port} ";
                }else{
                $dsn .= "host={$this->options['host']} ";
            }               

            }
            else{
                $dsn .= "host={$this->options['host']} ";
            }           

        }
$dsn .= "dbname={$this->options['database']} user={$this->options['user']} password={$this->options['password']}";//left as is
```