# Error connecting to PGSQL database in Joomla

Tags: postgresql, joomla, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to install Joomla using Postgres and in the installer I have the following error:

`Could not connect to the database. Connector returned number: Error connecting to PGSQL database.`

This isn't telling me very much. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the installer does not return the real error.

Here are some **general tips:**

- make sure the provided database already exists
- check if your database needs some specific settings, such as a different port or `sslmode=require`

**Put your connection details in a normal php file** and run the script, having error reporting enabled:

```
<?php
$connection = 'host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=joomla3 user=postgres password=postgres';
$dbconn = pg_connect($connection);

var_dump($dbconn);
```

When running the script you might get a proper error. When you get a resource, the connection is successful: `resource(4) of type (pgsql link)`

Answer (score 0):

Check selinux configuration:

```
$ sudo setenforce Permissive
```

and try again. If it works you can disable selinux at /etc/selinux/config and change the line

```
SELINUX=enforcing
```

by

```
 SELINUX=permissive
```